# error_log is not working as expected in functions.php file

Tags: php, errors, debug, wp-debug

Error log on my index file get logged in the `error_log.txt` file but the same error log is not working in the `functions.php` file. I am using the latest WordPress and `PHP 7.0.` I am not using any plugin as well.

```
error_log("Hello there is an error");
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem: calling `error_log()` from `wp-config.php` works, but calling it from `functions.php` does not work for me.

I couldn't solve this issue but I've found a workaround that allowed me to do some sort of debugging at least. I gave up on `error_log()` and just wrote an own function that logs into a given file:

```
function mylog($txt) {
    file_put_contents('/home/myuser/logs/mylog.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: Great alternative, I'm doing API calls that are skipping `wp-config` and this saved me

Answer (score 5):

If you have this set in your wp_config;

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

it will save the logs to /wp-content/debug.log file instead of the default Apache error.log

Answer (score 2):

In order for `error_log()` to do anything, you do need to have the `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` constants set to true in your wp-config.php. (See: [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in the Codex for more information.)

According to [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330039/how-can-i-use-error-log-with-wordpress), you should also set `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` for `error_log()` to function.  Note that you can set it to true OR false, but it evidently needs to be defined.